# Extract even-numbered and odd-numbered pages of a PDF into two separate PDFs

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I have a PDF that consists of several hundred pages of bilingual text. Since I need to use OCR on each language separately, I want to grab the even and odd pages and make two separate PDFs, using `convert` or `ghostscript`. The language I want to do first is on the odd-numbered pages. What `convert` or `ghostscript` command can I use to grab these and write them to a new file?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use ImageMagick or Ghostscript, as opposed to more appropriate tools?

Comment: @Gilles nope. pdftk works for me. thanks...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd do it with [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).

```
pdftk A=all.pdf cat Aodd output odd.pdf
pdftk A=all.pdf cat Aeven output even.pdf
```

Answer (score 9):

*pdftk* is not Open Source any longer, unfortunately. (That is a long story.)

Plain *gs* engine can do it, though:

```
  gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite     \
     -sPageList=odd         \
     -sOutputFile=odd.pdf   \
     -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE      \
     file.pdf
```

Then substitute 'odd' with 'even' to select even pages.

Answer (score 5):

With `poppler-utils` tools you could first extract single pages with `pdfseparate`:

```
pdfseparate infile.pdf piece-%d.pdf
```

into pieces like `piece-1.pdf`, `piece-2.pdf` ... `piece-n.pdf` where `n` is the total number of pages in your original pdf.

You could then join them with `pdfunite` (and a shell that supports using an increment value with range expansion: `{<START>..<END>..<INCR>}`):

```
pdfunite piece-{1..n..2}.pdf odd.pdf
pdfunite piece-{2..n..2}.pdf even.pdf
```

Finally, remove the pieces:

```
rm piece-{1..n}.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`qpdf`](https://qpdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#page-ranges)

```bash
qpdf --empty --pages input.pdf 1-z:even -- even.pdf
qpdf --empty --pages input.pdf 1-z:odd  --  odd.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `pdftocairo` from Poppler:

```
pdftocairo -pdf -e input.pdf output.pdf
```

for odd pages, and:

```
pdftocairo -pdf -o input.pdf output.pdf
```

for even pages.

!! Keep in mind only that currently (pdftocairo v. 0.80.0) there is a bug:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/issues/873 and odd and even pages options are mixed up. ))